# gvim profile for perl programming

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim, profile

can you get some good easy gvim profile file for perl programming ?

Comment: Should be on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [Perl IDE extension](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556) called perl-support.vim available on vim.org.  See the [documentation](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/perlsupport.html) and [hotkey map (PDF)](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-perl/perl-hot-keys.pdf).  It seems built for gvim or other vim-in-desktop-environments, though.  (Oh, and [Manni hates it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573782/what-are-your-suggestions-for-an-ideal-vim-configuration-for-perl-development/1581673#1581673).)

The SO question Manni links to is actually pretty extensive -- the questioner added the good suggestions into the question body.  It includes a lot of other Perl-related vim plugins and `.vimrc` tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the answers to this question over on stackoverflow.com: [What are your suggestions for an ideal Vim configuration for Perl development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573782/what-are-your-suggestions-for-an-ideal-vim-configuration-for-perl-development)